# Should I use only Fragments or combination of Activity and Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

Trying to make an Android application using Fragments, I've problems choosing the "right" structure in this part:

[image]

This is supposed to be a certain part of the application where the user should create a new entity (of type A). The entity consists of a couple of Strings and one subentity called B, and at last another subentity called C. I would like the user to choose among B and C from different Listviews (which I'm planning to place in different Fragments). This Fragments should also be used in different other places in the application.

The question is whether the "form" for entering data for entity A should be placed in an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), or another Fragment? Should I use FragmentTransactions to switch between all of the 3 Fragments, or should A be an Activity and B and C be Fragments which (in some kind of way) will be overlaying the Activity when clicking to select theese?

Thanks in advance for some feedback regarding my structure. Maybe I'm completely wrong and there should be another "better" way?

Comment: You need at least one `Activity`.

Comment: I understand that I need an activity to host the fragments, but my question is whether I should place common textfields inside the activity layout, or in a separate Fragment layout as a "main fragment" for the activity?

Comment: Fragments are hosted inside Activities. So most likely in your Fragments.

Comment: So you mean there's a specific reason that I shouldn't host the textfields within the activity context?

Comment: for what reason? This question is off topic anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "it depends"! ;)

But with the assumptions, that you want to support smartphones and tablets and create a flexible, future proof app you should use a Fragment for A, too.

It gives you more flexibility on future changes and improvements for the app. For example a (hypothetical) scenario on a large tablet. Some reasons to use a Fragment in your case:

- On the left side of the screen FragmentA, on the right side FragementB or FragmentC. That use case was one of the reasons for fragments. See the [fragment trainig](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) for a visual description.
- It's much easier to store the user input with a fragment. When a user switchs back from FragmentB/C to FragmentA you can show this (still existing) fragment with all the user input with minimal expense.
- The code is (maybe) more clear, if you make a strict separation between the roles of fragments and activities. Fragments contain your layout/task-specific content and Activity manage the visible app-lifecycle and general jobs. Sure you want a mix of activities with layouts+logic and some just with fragment management?

Comment: Thanks, sounds like it should be 3 Fragments after all. The problem I have here is the navigation structure when pressing the "back-button" on the device. Since I always want the user to navigate back to Fragment A when he/she is in Fragment B or C, but once the user has navigated A -> B -> A -> C and then pressing back, I want it to go to A and then out of the activity. Is it correct to add all fragments to the transaction initially, and then replace, or should i "remove" and then "add" again when navigating?

Comment: So you use _addBacktack()_ in your code as explained in the [training](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments)? There is an explanation about _addOnBackStackChangedListener_, to solve such problems (there some threads in stackoverflow about backstack and fragments for additional help)